# How to insert a triangle/contour plot generated with GetDist into a Matplotlib subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm doing some analysis on MCMC samples and I'm using the [GetDist](https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) python package to create my contour plots. However the contour plots are only a part of the whole analysis, and I would like to show some other plots along with the contour plot in the same figure.

I'm using matplotlib to generate all my other plots, so my question is: is there any way to have a GetDist plot in a matplotlib subplot, so that I have a matplotlib figure with multiple plots and a GetDist plot in it?

I'm using GridSpec to split the figure in subplots (and also to split subplots in subsubplots).
I tried to set a particular subplot as the current axis before creating the triangle plot, and I also tried to look at the GetDist source code to find a way to pass the wanted subplot as an argument to GetDist, but with no luck.

Right now, my code looks something like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import getdist.plots
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np
import numpy.random

N = 4
# Generate mock random data
chain = np.array([numpy.random.normal(loc=(i+0.5), scale=(i+0.5), size=100000) for i in xrange(N)])
Names = [str(unichr(i+97)) for i in xrange(N)]
Labels = [str(unichr(i+97)) for i in xrange(N)]
Sample = getdist.MCSamples(samples=chain.T, names=Names, labels=Labels)

#Set up plot layout
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10.5,12.5))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 2, width_ratios=[2,3], height_ratios=[10,0.5,4], wspace=0.2, hspace=.05)
Lplot = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(N, 1, subplot_spec=gs[0,0], hspace=0.)
Rplot = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2,1,subplot_spec=gs[0,1], height_ratios=[4,1.265])
Dplot = plt.subplot(gs[2,0:2])
axL = [plt.subplot(Lplot[i]) for i in xrange(N)]
axR = plt.subplot(Rplot[1])
GD = plt.subplot(Rplot[0])

for i in axL+[axR]+[GD]+[Dplot]: i.set_xticks([]); i.set_yticks([])

plt.sca(GD)
# Generate triangle plot
g = getdist.plots.getSubplotPlotter()
g.triangle_plot(Sample, filled=True)
plt.savefig("outfile.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

I would like to have my contour plot in the "GD" subplot.
Any help?

Comment: It seems like `GetDist` does not allow to pass (a set of) axes to their plotting functions, but rather creates the figure and axes itself. This only leaves the option to first create the GetDist plot and add your other plots to that existing figure. This is for sure cumbersome and non-ideal. Maybe the maintainers can be convinced to add an `axes` argument to their plotting functions, which at least in the long run  would help with this?